# Why does the same vsnprintf code output differently on Windows (MSVC) and Unix (Clang)

Tags: c++, windows, unix, printf

On Unix (Clang 3.8.1), this code outputs:

> 6: 32
>
> 8: a8e

On Windows (MSVC 19.00.24215.1), this code outputs:

> 6: 12345
>
> 6: a12345e

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdarg.h>

static std::string getFormattedString(const char* fmt, va_list ap) {
  int count = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, ap) + 1;
  std::cout << count << ": ";
  if (count <= 0) { return "unable to format message"; }

  std::string result = std::string(count, '\0');
  if (vsnprintf(&result[0], count, fmt, ap) < 0) { return "error";}

  return result;
}

static std::string getFormattedString(const char* fmt, ...) {
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, fmt);
  std::string result = getFormattedString(fmt, ap);
  va_end(ap);
  return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::cout << getFormattedString("%d", 12345).c_str() << "\n";
  std::cout << getFormattedString("a%de", 12345).c_str() << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Interestingly, they both get the correct count, but on my Linux and OS X machines, this code outputs an incorrect result. What's causing this? Have I incurred UB somewhere?

Comment: Can you overload function names with varargs?

Comment: @BoBTFish seems like you can, this does compile fine

Comment: @HBellamy Unix and Windows are operating systems, not compilers.  Please mention the actual compilers used.

Comment: `vsnprintf` modifies `ap` so the two times you call it, you are passing a different `ap`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sorry, I thought that the actual runtime implementation of `vsnprintf` depends not on the compiler, but on the system?

Comment: @RaymondChen interesting, I'll investigate. If you answer this question, could you also clarify why I get 32 and 8 as outputs?

Comment: @HBellamy [Here is gcc output](http://rextester.com/JRRU29394).  To constrast, here is [VC++ 2015](http://rextester.com/FHZOWW88332)

Comment: @HBellamy *could you also clarify why I get 32 and 8 as outputs* -- Implementing "..." is implementation-defined.  Unless you want to get into the weeds of how each compiler implements varargs, the answer is not that simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @RaymondChen said in the comments, vsnprintf modifies ap.  If you want to reuse the va_list, you have to make a copy with va_copy:

```
static std::string getFormattedString(const char* fmt, va_list ap) {
    va_list ap2;
    va_copy(ap2, ap);
    int count = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, ap) + 1;
    std::cout << count << ": ";
    if (count <= 0) { return "unable to format message"; }

    std::string result = std::string(count, '\0');
    if (vsnprintf(&result[0], count, fmt, ap2) < 0) { return "error";}
    std::cout << result.size() << ' ' << strlen(result.c_str()) << '\n';

    return result;
}
```

This will use the original list twice, and produce the correct result.

Comment: Don't forget to `va_end(ap2)`.